How could technology be used to create a false alibi?
Lots of criminals are caught by Police because of technology - mobile phone GPS, vehicle tracking data, Smart watches, not to mention CCTV, Ring doorbells and dash cams. How would someone manipulate the technology to work for them and become their alibi? Ie without hacking. Just using the tech the way it is supposed to be used - obviously without just turning their phone off!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Mandatory prerequisite viewing: The Capture (British TV series 2019–2022). Subtitle: seeing is deceiving. And, of course, Yesterday, upon the stair, I met a man who wasn't there; he wasn't there again today: I wish, I wish he'd go away (Hughes Mearns, 1899).

A magician never reveals their tricks.

This site is for worldbuilding, ie developing your world.  This question is asking us to develop or brainstorm your story, not your world, which makes it off-topic.  (It's also far too broad, but even if it were narrowed down, it still wouldn't be worldbuilding.)

https://security.stackexchange.com/ might be a better stack for this question

Thank you all for your help!

Posted on Security.SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/278611/59741

Some time ago I saw the performance of an artist who put a bunch of smartphones in a trolley and slowly carried them along a road, showing how some navigation apps would interpret that as an ongoing traffic jam and would show the road packed with traffic while in reality the road was almost empty and got more and more empty as drivers avoided it to avoid the virtual traffic jam.
Someone wanting to hide their traces could do something based on that concept: put their smartphone or another tracking device on a certain path, for example in a car or bicycle going around the city, so that its presence is recorded in various cells far away from the place where they actually are to do the deed, so that they seems to be somewhere else at the time when it happened.
It won't make an 100% solid alibi, but it will mud the waters for some time.

Excellent. Thank you. Exactly the sort of thing I’m looking for!

It's easier to make false data than alter or erase real data.
Your question doesn't specify, but I think you want a solution for a guilty person to create a false alibi.  Without "hacking", you're not going to alter the data that's captured by cell phones, cameras, etc.  Your next best solution would be to provide fake data that's more attractive or obvious than the real data.
For example, have an accomplice dress in your most recognizable clothes and be seen in public with your car, with your family or friends (wearing a hat and sunglasses to hide the differences), while you go commit the crime dressed completely differently, using someone else's car, etc.  If you're lucky, the police will rule you out as a suspect without looking too closely at things.
Another way to possibly defeat surveillance technology without hacking is to flood the data stream with more data than they can sort through.  Burglarize that house at the same hour the local high school gets out, so there are dozens of teenagers and cell phones all on the same street at the same time.  Too many suspects to chase down, and since you will have left your cell phone at home, you might be overlooked entirely.

This is really great - thank you for taking the time to answer

@KatherinePalmano, the way it works here, if you find an answer useful, you can upvote it. Then you accept the one which solved your problem. You can upvote as many as you want, accept only one.

You can not.
There are various ways to manipulate technology, we can call that hacking. Neither of them is simple, simply because they were designed to prevent or obstruct hacking.
Here we have a network of eavesdropping technologies, all of them working independently. Maybe hacking some of them is not impossible, hacking all of them is.
Except...
Although you can only lose against electronics on the global level, a local win is not impossible.
What is not impossible, only hard: to hack an enough amount of local electronics to provide a fake trace, or to obstruct eavesdropping et all. Here we might have also an advantage if the eavesdropping authorities overly trust them. I.e. imageine a world where there is no more real police. And a "police investigation" means only that they collect the camera recordings and robotically accept what they see. In such a world, if you find a way to manipulate the recordings by AI, can mislead the authorities.
That is already not impossible, only hard.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. Very much appreciated!

Not every manipulation of technology is hacking.  Technology collects data, but it does not guarantee that such data is any good.  Holding a rubber mat over your head to beat thermal sensors, wearing a mask to beat facial recognition, leaving your phone at home to beat GPS, and any variety of social engineering are all ways to beat technology that don't involve any actual hacking abilities.
